# sp_dropuser stored procedure vs drop user statement in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

As the title suggest, which choice is preferable (in what conditions if any) for removing a user from the database: `sp_dropuser` stored procedure or `DROP USER` command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sp_dropuser` is being deprecated in favour of `DROP USER`.

To quote MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189758.aspx):

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use DROP USER instead.

Therefore `DROP USER` is the one to go with.

The same holds for other similar stored procs such as `sp_adduser`.